# Using w3 svg icon in a wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, icons, w3c

I've bought a WordPress theme (Urbango). This is an aggregation webpage theme where various categories are relevant. For each category, a specific w3 svg icon is used (see code below). The one below is for one specific icon:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="42.105px" height="43.688px" viewBox="0 0 42.105 43.688" enable-background="new 0 0 42.105 43.688" xml:space="preserve"><g><circle stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="7.044" cy="36.357" r="5.793"/><line stroke-width="2" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="24.403" y1="18.373" x2="20.573" y2="23.475"/><path stroke-width="2" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M15.862,16.209 l10.295-14.7c0,0,0.691,1.682,1.154,4.071"/><line stroke-width="2" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="7.958" y1="27.492" x2="10.921" y2="23.263"/><path stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M27.355,41.307 c-0.843,0.623-1.865,1.024-2.987,1.112c-3.19,0.249-5.978-2.135-6.228-5.325c-0.25-3.19,2.133-5.978,5.325-6.227 c0.395-0.031,0.785-0.021,1.164,0.025"/><path stroke-width="2" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M23.388,27.707 L5.831,1.25c0,0-5.153,6.378-1.589,12.418L16.65,31.635"/><g><line stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="40.77" y1="37.589" x2="34.275" y2="37.589"/><line stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="40.77" y1="33.541" x2="34.275" y2="33.541"/><line stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="40.77" y1="29.492" x2="34.275" y2="29.492"/><line stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="40.77" y1="25.444" x2="34.275" y2="25.444"/><line stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="40.77" y1="21.395" x2="34.275" y2="21.395"/><line stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="40.77" y1="13.298" x2="34.275" y2="13.298"/><line stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="40.77" y1="17.347" x2="34.275" y2="17.347"/><line stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="40.77" y1="9.25" x2="34.275" y2="9.25"/></g><g><g><circle stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="15.831" cy="23.277" r="0.547"/></g></g><path stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M40.855,41.625l-8.293,0 c-1.381,0-2.483-2.134-2.483-2.134c-1.459-2.897-2.566-7.146-2.566-16.043V23.39c0-8.896,1.106-13.146,2.566-16.043 c0,0,1.103-2.133,2.483-2.133l8.293,0"/></g></svg>
```

I don't get anything out of this coding. Unfortunately, however, it needs to be like that as it obviously also defines the way its visualized in different areas of the pages.

My question: Which part of this code needs to be changed so that I can just have the same logic for another icon? E.g. changing this scissors icon into w.g. a burger menu icon.

Comment: Hi Paul, This is not "code" per say but "image encoding". You can't re-create an other icon from that. you should take a look at a great icon library called [Fontawesome](https://fontawesome.com/), really friendly to use and also (partly) free.